# Gridview in fragment giving a error when pass data to the adapter

Tags: android, shuffle, android-gridview

```
listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
        listFlag = new ArrayList<String>();

        listCountry.add("name");
        listFlag.add("https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/cartoon/4-2-cartoon-transparent.png");
        listCountry.add("one");
        listFlag.add("https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/cartoon/4-2-cartoon-transparent.png");  
mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(getActivity(),listCountry, listFlag);
                gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Above code is in the Fragement

and this is the GridviewAdapter.java code

```
 public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
        private ArrayList<String> listFlag;
        private Activity activity;

        public GridviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listCountry, ArrayList<String> listFlag) {
            super();
            this.listCountry = listCountry;
            this.listFlag = listFlag;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return listCountry.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return listCountry.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder
        {
            public ImageView imgViewFlag;
            public TextView txtViewTitle;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder view;
            LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

            if(convertView==null) {
                view = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.simple_list, null);

                view.txtViewTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                view.imgViewFlag = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                convertView.setTag(view);
            }
            else
            {
                view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
            Picasso.get().load(listFlag.get(position)).resize(100,100).into(view.imgViewFlag);
            return convertView;
        }

  }
```

App crashes when adapter passes data i also tried with the context. Please check and provide me a solution. When adapter passes data from fragment to the adapter. Then app crashes so please provide me a solution so that app will not be crash.

Log

```
2019-07-22 15:50:23.394 2238-2268/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-07-22 15:50:25.313 21653-21787/com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 E/chromium: [ERROR:adm_helpers.cc(73)] Failed to query stereo recording.
2019-07-22 15:50:25.919 21550-21550/com.allinone E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(175)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
2019-07-22 15:50:25.920 21550-21550/com.allinone E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(175)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
2019-07-22 15:50:26.001 21550-21550/com.allinone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.allinone, PID: 21550
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.allinone.Shopping.prepareList(Shopping.java:68)
        at com.allinone.Shopping.onCreateView(Shopping.java:37)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
        at com.allinone.MainActivity$1.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:94)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1608)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1601)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1569)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1874)
        at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:2059)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)


    --------- beginning of system
2019-07-22 15:50:26.189 2238-2371/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f48eada com.allinone/com.allinone.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-07-22 15:50:26.202 21653-21668/com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 E/chromium: [ERROR:broker_posix.cc(106)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)
2019-07-22 15:50:26.202 21653-21668/com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 E/chromium: [ERROR:broker_posix.cc(106)] Error sending sync broker message: Broken pipe (32)
2019-07-22 15:50:26.384 2238-2272/system_process E/libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99040 pid 21653: No such file or directory
2019-07-22 15:50:26.902 3498-3498/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/OverlaySController: Calling with an invalid UID, the interface will not work
2019-07-22 15:50:26.971 1877-1882/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-07-22 15:50:27.148 1877-2113/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-07-22 15:50:28.332 3498-21345/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/EntrySyncManager: Cannot determine account name: drop request
2019-07-22 15:50:28.332 3498-21345/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/NowController: Failed to access data from EntryProvider. ExecutionException.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.eA(SourceFile:85)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.get(SourceFile:23)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.l.get(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:49)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.sidekick.main.h.n: Could not complete scheduled request to refresh entries. ClientErrorCode: 3
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.ar.az(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.q.ap(SourceFile:7)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.run(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bt.execute(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.b(SourceFile:275)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.addListener(SourceFile:135)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.p.b(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:16)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.h.a(SourceFile:13)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbB(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.be.cbA(SourceFile:181) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.nowstream.b.a.bh.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.at.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6) 
2019-07-22 15:50:29.045 1873-3005/? E/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl: getInputForAttr permission denied: recording not allowed for uid 10039 pid 3498
2019-07-22 15:50:29.045 1873-3005/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecord() checkRecordThread_l failed
2019-07-22 15:50:29.045 3498-21833/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -22
2019-07-22 15:50:29.045 3498-21833/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -22
2019-07-22 15:50:29.053 3498-21833/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
2019-07-22 15:50:29.055 3498-21833/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2019-07-22 15:50:29.057 3498-21833/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2019-07-22 15:50:29.238 2872-21263/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7 [CONTEXT service_id=47 ]
2019-07-22 15:50:29.431 2872-2872/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2019-07-22 15:50:29.521 2872-2872/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
2019-07-22 15:50:29.960 21604-21627/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.as.allapps.actionsettingprovider
2019-07-22 15:50:29.960 21604-21627/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActionsController: write setting failed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.google.android.as.allapps.actionsettingprovider
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1583)
        at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.d.handleMessage(SourceFile:268)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-07-22 15:50:30.055 21604-21604/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: When there's a crash, there's a crash log. You can have a look at [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for some troubleshooting instructions. The crash log will specify the exception type and the exact code line.

Comment: can't you resolve it without log. i am not using log.

Comment: You can check log in your editor. You can see there is a tab with the name "logcat".Click on that to see the error. And Without looking at the logs it is hard to determine the error from such a small block of code.

Comment: Please share crash logs.Which exception you are getting ?

Comment: check log if you can understand this

Comment: I suggest using `RecyclerView`with `GridLayoutManager` for better performance and higher flexibility.

Comment: Seems like your gridView is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you haven't initialized your `gridView` object before you call `setAdapter()` method on it.
First you have to initialize it using `gridView = res.findViewById(R.id.your_grid_view_id_in_your_xml_file)` or `gridView = new GridView(context)` then call the `setAdapter()` method.

Comment: Thanks for this @Mehrbod Khiabani . App Stopped crashing. I want to know why this initialization not required in the Activity. But Data is not displaying in the Fragment.

Comment: So Please Tell me What is this issue that Adapter not Showing Data.

Comment: Adapter Returns get Count = 9, But Data not display on the grid view adapter